# Laravel css using the elixir function not working properly on xampp

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-5, xampp

I created a versioned css file using:

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass('demo.scss')
    .version('css/demo.css');
});
```

the file is under `public/build/demo-34f5737738.css`, according to the documentation the file should be linked this way:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ elixir("css/demo.css") }}"`

however the stylesheet is not being applied when running in Xampp, but it's working when I start a server via command:  `php artisan serve`.
Any idea of why this is happening, or does Xampp needs a special setup before working with Laravel. Thanks!

Comment: When you inspect element, what is the URL displayed for the css stylesheet? Is it the good one? Is your URL based on a folder, like `http://localhost/project/public/` ? The elixir function might apply a `/css/demo.css` URL and if it is the case, your browser would look in the `http://localhost/css` folder...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting absolute path via `asset` will solve that issue:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ issue("css/demo.css") }}"
```

Comment: @erick.chali glad it helped. I guess, you should set answer as correct, if you think so. That's how things work here)